# How to programmatically test if ngrok is already running

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, ngrok

We have ran [ngrok](http://ngrok.com/) on a localhost PORT say http://localhost:4000. We can **manually** test if the ngrok is already runing or not by using the following steps:

## Check if ngrok is already running:

- Hit http://127.0.0.1:4040/status

If the connection happens successfully, the following visual will show up:

[image: ngrok online]

If the above visual is not showing, ngrok is not running at all.

- Under **Tunnels** section, the following visual will show up:

[image: localhost PORT connected to ngrok online]

If the above visual is not showing, ngrok is not running on PORT 4000.

To start ngrok on http://localhost:4000, we need to run `ngrok http 4000`. After running this command, the above visuals will show up.

Is there some [programmatic way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45452674/2404470#comment77866631_45452789) to determine if ngrok is already running on the port?

Answer (score 7):

For others stumbling by this question,
Make a request to http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels using curl or any request library in the programming language of your choice. It returns a JSON formatted response of the ngrok tunnels and their urls, which you can obtain.. If it does not return anything, it means ngrok is not running

Eg for python:

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
req = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:4040/api/tunnels')
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')
tunnelsjson = json.loads(soup.find('p').text)
url = tunnelsjson['tunnels'][0]['public_url']
print(url)
```

Comment: If you are running multiple ngrok servers, you will need to use :4041, :4042, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Run this command to see using ports:

```
sudo lsof -PiTCP -sTCP:LISTEN
```

Comment: Appreciate this! However, is there a way to check this using some kind of code?

Answer (score 1):

You can check it by python:

```
import socket;
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
result = sock.connect_ex(('127.0.0.1',4000))
print(result)
if result == 0:
    print "Port is not open"
else:
    print "Port is open"
```

P.S. if port is in use, result is 0, if not it is 61.

Answer (score 1):

Run netstat -tulnap | grep ngrok

netstat -tulnap shows which processes are running on the machine
grep ngrok filters for the ngrok processes.

Comment: I wanted to see a programmatic javascript implementation of this